# How can I calculate a percentage change from the previous month in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have created a table that has two columns: the first one containing the name of several campaigns and the second one containing their investment. In addition, this table has a month filter, so that the campaign investments for only one month appear.

To this table I want to add a third column in which the percentage variation with respect to the previous month appears.

I have tried to do it with the following code, but as the table does not show the previous month, the field is blank.

```
(ZN(SUM([Investment])) - LOOKUP(ZN(SUM([Investment])), -1)) / ABS(LOOKUP(ZN(SUM([Inversión])), -1))
```

How can I calculate it?

Another option that has occurred to me is to create a calculated field in which the investment of the previous month appears directly and from there to make the percentage variation, but I have not been able to do it either.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**Steps**

1. Create a copy of the field of you want to calculate % different from. You can do this by pressing down **command** button on mac and dragging the field to the side.[image]
2. Click on the second field you have added. Click on **quick table calculation and percent difference**[image]
3. Click on **edit table calculation**[image]
4. Select **relative to previous** [image]

Hope this helps!